# When are two vectors parallel if the vectors are $5e_1-3e_2+\alpha e_3$ and $\beta e_1 + 2e_2 + 3e_3$

Tags: vector-spaces

When are two vectors parallel if the vectors are  $$5e_1-3e_2+\alpha e_3$$ and $$\beta e_1 + 2e_2 + 3e_3$$
The alpha and beta are parameters.

Comment: Someone edited your title to make it take up less vertical space (thanks @Gigili). This is done to prevent questions from dominating the feed on the main page. In particular, it is understood that display equations (with `$$`) should not be used in titles. I figured I'd tell you so that you may learn from it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two vector $\vec {n_1}$ and $\vec{n_2}$ are parallel when we can write them in this way

$\vec {n_1}=k\cdot \vec{n_2}\,$ where k  is any scaler quantity.

so given vectors are parallel when 
$$
\dfrac5{\beta}=\dfrac{-3}{2}=\dfrac{\alpha}{3}
$$
In one of the other answer shown:  $\vec {n_1}\times \vec {n_2}=\vec 0\implies \vec{n_1}||\vec{n_2}$

$\vec {n_1}\times \vec {n_2}$ can be calculated as:

$\vec {n_1}\times \vec {n_2}=\begin{vmatrix} {e_1} &{e_2} & {e_3}\\
5 & -3 & \alpha \\
\beta & 2 & 3
\end{vmatrix}$ 
$$\vec {n_1}\times \vec {n_2}=e_1((-3\times 3)-(2\times \alpha))-e_2((5\times 3)-(\alpha\times\beta))+e_3(5\times 2-(-3\times \beta))$$
$$\vec {n_1}\times \vec {n_2}=e_1(-9-2\alpha)-e_2(15-\alpha\beta)+e_3(10+3\beta)$$

Answer (score 1):

Two vectors $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ are parallel if
$$
\vec u = t \vec v
$$
for some $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

You have 
$$
\vec u = 5 \vec {e_1} - 3 \vec {e_2} + \alpha \vec {e_3} = (5,-3,\alpha)
$$
and
$$
\vec v = \beta \vec {e_1} + 2\vec {e_2} + 3 \vec {e_3} = (\beta,2,3)
$$
Your condition is then
$$
(5,-3,\alpha) = t (\beta,2,3) = (\beta t, 2t, 3t)
$$
and therefore
\begin{align*}
5 &= \beta t \\
-3 &= 2t \\
\alpha &= 3t
\end{align*}
You have 3 equations and 3 unknowns $t,\alpha,\beta$...

Comment: Where do I go from here?

Comment: Solve the system to get $\alpha$ and $\beta$

Comment: How do I "solve" it?

Comment: From second equation you get $t=-\frac32$ and then from first equation $\beta = -\frac{10}{3}$ and from third equation $\alpha=-\frac92$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Two vectors are parallel iff their cross product is zero:

$$(5e_1-3e_2+\alpha e_3)\times(\beta e_1+2e_2+3e_3)=(-9-2\alpha)e_1+(\alpha\beta-15)e_2+(10+3\beta)e_3\implies$$

$$\implies \alpha=-\frac92\;\;\ldots\; etc.$$

**Or:**

Two vectors are parallel iff their linearly dependent iff one is a scalar multiple of the other one. You'll get, of course, the same as above.